# Diamond Question marks with set headers

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

When changing the language to German on my website, I am produced with black diamonds with question marks. I have set the charset (UTF-8) in my meta tags and I am also producing the browser with a UTF-8 header. What else could be the cause of this?

I'm setting the header here, but I'm not sure if I need to do anything else. I don't often come across this problem, so it's not something I'm familiar with.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/raw/juuh00h6/

Pay attention to App.setLang() (last function) which is what actually sets the text on most elements. Please see here: http://pastebin.com/CV9QpxGJ for my lang file ("lang.js").

See it in action: http://jwelford.co.uk/?lang=de

Comment: You tagged this PHP, but didn't post any code. PHP has its own issues with character sets. Where is your output coming from, and have you done anything with PHP to handle the character set issue?

Comment: There's a lot more to it than that. I strongly recommend that you read [PHP the Right Way on this topic](http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8).

Comment: "__All output is via Javascript and the only PHP used is to set headers...__" Why did you use the php tag ? your problem is related with JavaScript encoding,  not php. Take a look at http://ecmanaut.blogspot.fr/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

Comment: Also if you can, paste the javascript you are using to give the output to show the entire program, you could use something like https://jsfiddle.net/ to show your entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) and [mb_http_output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-output.php)

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');

$string = '"Stehler" ist in diesem Sinne ein mögliches Wort im Deutschen , das aber durch das bekannte Wort "Dieb" verhindert wird .';


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo $string;
```

---

## Output:

> "Stehler" ist in diesem Sinne ein mögliches Wort im Deutschen , das
>   aber durch das bekannte Wort "Dieb" verhindert wird .

---

## Note

If you need to convert the string to upper or lower case, use the [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), i.e.:

```
mb_strtoupper($string);
mb_strtolower($string);
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/QHQhLf

Comment: Please define "__did not solve my problem__", and post an example of input.

Comment: This is the only PHP code used in my index page. 

     mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
 mb_http_output('UTF-8');
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: I don't see any php on your question, please update your question with the php you're using and the string with problem.

Comment: If you went to the link provided you would see it is not just a single string I am having problems with. The whole HTML page (when presented in German, French etc...) is causing issues. All output is via Javascript and the only PHP used is to set headers, send mail & regulate cookies.